# Is there a plugin to make ActiveX Code cross browser compatible

Tags: javascript, web-applications, cross-browser, web, activex

I'm currently working on a web application I didn't build. My current mission is to make it cross browser compatible. It has certain requests written in ActiveX. My question is, is there a plug in, or short cut (per se) to make this application work in all modern browsers.

Comment: Why do you need ActiveX? Maybe you can do whatever you are doing without ActiveX..

Comment: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ActiveX

Answer (score 1):

FireBreath is a C++ wrapper which gives you the possiblity to create a wrapper over an ActiveX, so they can be supported in other browsers.
Checkout http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/About+FireBreath

Ziv

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. ActiveX is a MSIE-only technique. You can safely assume that it will **never** be supported in any other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. It isn't really a feasible project anyway since ActiveX involves binary code that depends on Windows APIs. It would be difficult to get it to work on non-Windows platforms (WINE is far from perfect) and require architecture emulation to get it to work on non-x86 compatible platforms.